# Casting type to derived interface for use in generic method

Tags: c#

I have two interfaces, one deriving from the other

```
public interface IOptions
{
}

public interface IMigratedOptions : IOptions
{
}
```

I have a `StorageProvider` class, with generic methods making use of the two interfaces

```
public class StorageProvider
{
    public T LoadDataOrNull<T>() where T : class, IOptions, new()
    {
        var temp = new T();
        return _baseStorageProvider.LoadData(temp.OptionGuid);
    }

    public T LoadOldDataOrNull<T>() where T : class, IMigratedOptions, new()
    {
        var temp = new T();
        return _baseStorageProvider.LoadData(temp.OldOptionGuid);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a generic service class that requires `T` to implement `IOptions`

```
public abstract class ServiceWithOptions<T> : IServiceWithOptions<T> where T : class, IOptions, new()
{
    public T LoadOptions()
    {
        T options = new();
        if (!typeof(IMigratedOptions).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            options = StorageProvider.LoadDataOrNull<T>();
        else
            options = StorageProvider.LoadOldDataOrNull<T>();

        return options ;
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem: sometimes the `T` passed to `ServiceWithOptions` will implement `IMigratedOptions` and sometimes not.

In `LoadOptions()` I can check whether or not it is the case with `typeof(IMigratedOptions).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)`.

But even If I can verify that `T` implements `IMigratedOptions`, I cannot use `StorageProvider.LoadOldDataOrNull<T>();`, I get the error `CS0311 The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StorageProvider.LoadOldDataOrNull<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'IMigratedOptions'.`

How do I go about casting my `T` to a `MigratedT` when I know `T` implements `IMigratedOptions`?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I get the question. You cast it by using the cast operator of course, e.g. `(IMigratedOptions)variableName`.

Comment: T is not a variable but a type in this scenario.

Comment: What does `// do stuff` do and why can you not split it further down the chain? Because once you've created the `T` you can do a normal `as` or `is` pattern check

Comment: @Charlieface 

`public T LoadDataOrNull<T>() where T : class, IOptions, new(){
 var temp = new T();
 return _baseStorageProvider.LoadData(temp.OptionGuid);
}` and
`public T LoadOldDataOrNull<T>() where T : class, IMigratedOptions, new()
{
 var temp = new T();
 return _baseStorageProvider.LoadData(temp.OldOptionGuid);
}`

`OldOptionGuid` only exists on `IMigratedOptions` classes.
I guess since I am creating a new instance of `T` anyway I could do the `IMigratedOptions` check inside my `LoadDataOrNull<T>()` method and avoid dealing with more generic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go further down the stack and rewrite `LoadDataOrNull`, because that is what creates the `T`.

So then you can use normal pattern matching to decide what to do.

```cs
public class StorageProvider
{
    public T LoadDataOrNull<T>() where T : class, IOptions, new()
    {
        var temp = new T();
        var guid = temp is IMigratedOptions migrated
            ? migrated.OldOptionGuid
            : temp.OptionGuid;
        return _baseStorageProvider.LoadData(guid);
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to be the simplest solution indeed. 
I am surprised it is seemingly impossible to cleanly cast my `T` to be used with `LoadOldDataOrNull<T>` , when we can easily verify whether it would meet the `where` clause requirement or not.